# Trick to delete session after going back in browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an issue. I have a list of recipes in my recipes index page. The idea is that when you click on a particular recipe, it carries you to the show page and stores the recipe id in session. The presence/absence of the id in session is integral to the workflow of the program. The session gets cleared when you create a sub-recipe or revisit the index page. However, when you click back on the browser (`to recipes/index`) without creating a resource, the recipe id remains in session and you no longer desire the value in the session. This causes the program to run into errors. How do I do it that the clicking of the back button also deletes the session

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions with the information you've provided:

1. Set a `before_action` on the index to clear the recipe id from the session.
2. Pass the recipe id to the show page via params then set it to an instance variable for use in the view.

I would choose the latter of these if possible. More info would allow a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved it by checking if the `request.referer` is the index page's url. If it is, then I clear the session.

Moving forward, you can handle cases like this by checking the header key `(request.headers["HTTP_REFERER"])` (also gotten by calling `request.referer`). This way regardless of the method you used to get to a page, you can always get its fidelity.